# "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" - SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to display a custom popup menu using a UIViewController.  I have written a function to enable the re-use of displaying the popup.  However, I keep getting the error above and I do not know how to handle the "nil".

SWIFT:

```
 func showPopUp(msg: String){

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let popUpVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popupEmpty") as! PopUpViewController
    popUpVC.messageLabel.text = msg  // ""Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" - SWIFT"
    self.present(popUpVC, animated: true, completion: nil) 

}
```

My msg parameter is not an optioanl type.  I am somewhat confused.

Comment: `messageLabel` isn't loaded yet. Use a `var messageLabelString` instead, and do `popUpVC.messageLabelString = msg` and in `viewDidLoad()` do `popUpVC.messageLabel.text = messageLabelString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`messageLabel`is `nil` until view loads ( even if connected properly )

```
class PopUpViewController:UIViewController {
  var sendedText = ""
}
```

then use

```
popUpVC.sendedText = msg
```

//

then set `sendedText` to the lbl inside `viewDidLoad`